# function perform on selecting specific dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am stuck with strange problem. i have dropdown populate values through db. after populating i append new value. no i want to call function when user select this new value.

```js
if($('#ab option:selected').text() === "Other")
{
 $('#txtbox').show();
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" id="ab" >
      <option select = "selected" value = "" >Select county </option>
  
      <?php
       $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db1");

//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}  
      $sql = "select county from tbl WHERE Code = 'a'";
      $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
          echo "<option value='".$row->id."'>".$row->county."</option>";
    
        }
  echo "<option value='".$row->id."'>Other";
      }
      ?>

    </select>
```

i have tried many things but nothing works

Comment: You need to close your last `<option>` tag. And all your options' values will be the exact same, is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [change event handler](https://api.jquery.com/change/) and move your code within the callback.

```
$('#ab').change(function(){
    if($(this).text() === "Other"){
        $('#txtbox').show();
    } else{ // add else part to hide the element
        $('#txtbox').hide();
    }
});
```

---

*FYI :* You can make your code more simple by using [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method.

```
$('#ab').change(function(){
    $('#txtbox').toggle($(this).text() === "Other");
});
```

---

You are missing a closing tag for the last `option` in server-side code.

```
echo "<option value='".$row->id."'>Other</option>";
// -- here -----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^----
```

---

FYI : For running jQuery code correctly after loading all element wrap code within [document ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: it does not trigger changefuntion

Comment: @Sarah_Salar :  share your rendered HTML and script in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Sarah_Salar : also check ur console.... And where are you placing the jquery code?

Comment: @Sarah_Salar : within document ready handler, header without document ready handler , footer, etc....

Comment: thanks! strangely this is what i am forgetting to put this inside document ready handler